# Cocos2d Delegate retain cycle

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I just cannot figure out this retain cycle, and would appreciate if someone could help me spot it.

I have a `RootController` object that holds strong a strong reference to a `RootView`.

```
@interface RootController : CCNode <TouchDelegate, GUIDelegate, ModelViewDelgate>
...
@property (nonatomic, weak) CCDirector *director;
@property (nonatomic) RootView *view;
...
@end

@implementation
- (id)init {
  ...
  _view = [[RootView alloc] initWithController:self];
  [self addChild:_view];
  ...
  }
  return self;
}
@end
```

I have a `RootView` object that holds a reference to the controller, as well as an `activeGame`, enabling me to swap between game types without needing to know the specifics other than it conforms to a `<TouchDelegate>` protocol:

```
@interface RootView : CCScene
...
@property (nonatomic, assign) RootController *controller;
@property (nonatomic) GameplayLayer <ModelViewDelgate> *activeGame;
...
@end

@implementation RootView
- (id)init {
   ...  
   self.activeGame = [[GameplayLayer alloc] initWithDelegate:_controller root:self type:type];
   [self addChild:self.activeGame];
   ...  
}
  return self;
}
@end
```

And lastly, I have the GameplayLayer, which is invoked by the RootView when necessary, and **should** be deallocated by the RootView:

```
@interface GameplayLayer : CCLayer <ModelViewDelgate, Updatable>
...
@property (nonatomic, assign) RootView *rootView;
@property (nonatomic, assign) RootController <TouchDelegate> *touchDelegate;
...
@end
```

When a controller class decides it's time to cleanup the game (usually a hard reset of the game), literally every other class in my project is deallocated except for this GameplayLayer, which never receives the dealloc method. What am I missing? Here is how I 'restart' my game...

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[RootController node]];
```

Comment: Are you releasing the `GameplayLayer` in `RootView`'s `dealloc`?

Comment: I set `_activeGame.touchDelegate`, `_activeGame.rootView`, and `_activeGame` to nil in that order.

Comment: Either `self.activeGame = nil;` or `[_activeGame release];`. Otherwise you're just nilling the pointer, not destroying the object. Or (best answer), convert to ARC.

Comment: It is an ARC project, but aren't we supposed to use _ modifiers in the init and dealloc methods?

Comment: If you're compiling with ARC, you shouldn't be using `assign` for your properties, you should be using `weak` (or `unsafe_unretained`). You also don't need to release ivars in `dealloc`. Also also, whether ARC or MRR, `RootView` shouldn't be clearing out `GameplayLayer`'s properties; that's `GameplayLayer`'s job.

Comment: I assumed that is where the problem lies. GameplayLayer does not ever call dealloc, so I tried to break the cycle with the parent node (RootView), but nothing seems to get GameplayLayer to dealloc.

Comment: it's very easy to create a retain cycle in cocos2d by having a child node hold a strong ref to one of its parents (ie sprite has strong ref to GameplayLayer). You probably wouldn't notice the gameplaylayer's child nodes not deallocing because the layer itself doesn't dealloc, but that's exactly where you need to check the obj relationship.

Comment: Strangely enough, the only child of that layer is a CCBatchNode. For some reason calling removeChild:_batch and removeAllChildren does not dealloc the batch node. Remove all children from the batch node works, however... getting warmer?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some thought-provoking questioning by @JoshCaswell and @LearnCocos2D, we were able to solve the problem. It turns out, there really wasn't a problem. As per requirements of Cocos2d, in the `onExit` method, you must tell the CCDirector to remove any touch delegates previously assigned to that CCNode. If you override that method, however, you must call `[super onExit]` before exiting the method, otherwise Cocos2d will fail to remove children, and thus certain elements will never dealloc.